# conditionnal time series

Tags: probability, stopping-times, time-series

I have 2 stochastic times series $(X_t)$, $(Y_t)$.
I would like to calculate the following quantity :

$$\Bbb E[ X_{(t+1)} \mid Y_t,t ]$$

Expectation of $(X)$ at time $(t+1)$ conditionned on values of $(Y_t, t)$.

Empirically, do I need to calculate the bivariate distribution of $(X_t,Y_t)$
as well the marginal distribution of $(X_t)$ ?

Also, tried to find some research on conditionnal time series, but could not find any ressource (apart the time series conditionned on itself at previous dates).

Comment: Any comments on this.

Comment: When you write $E[X_{t+1} \mid Y_t , t]$ do you mean conditioned on $Y_t$ and the filtration of $\{X_t\}$ up to time $t$ (sometimes denoted $\mathcal F_t$)? I.e. $E[X_t\mid t] = X_t$?

Comment: yes, conditionned on both filtrations.